# I am able to see a tab from lightning "App Launcher" while that tab is not added in current app

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, security, app-launcher

I have multiple apps in my org, irrespective of whichever app I use I am able to search and access one specific tab from lightning "App Launcher" menu.
Why is this so? I am an admin user in this org.

Answer (score 1):

for displaying a tab in an app - you need to add it:

1. go to lightning setup and search `app manager`:

[image]

2. choose the app you want and click `edit` on it's menu:

[image]

3. on the wizard that was opened, click `select items` on the top tab:

[image]

4. Select your tab and add it to your app
5. Now - this tab is in your app!!!